# Jackson: how to omit field inside nested object

Tags: java, spring, serialization, jackson, filtering

I have a pojo-like object with following structure:

```
@JsonFilter("MyFilter")
public MyDTO {
   public int id;
   public List<MyNestedDTO> nestedDTO;

   public MyNestedDTO {
       public int id;
       public String name;

       ... 
   }

   ...
}
```

I want to completely omit name-field from a serialized output. I use `SimpleBeanPropertyFilter` like this:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
PropertyFilter columnFilter = new SimpleBeanPropertyFilter() {
   @Override
   public void serializeAsField(Object pojo, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider, PropertyWriter writer)
   throws Exception {
      if (include(writer)) {
         if (writer.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("nestedDTO")) {
                        return;
         }
         writer.serializeAsField(pojo, jgen, provider);
      } else if (!jgen.canOmitFields()) {
         writer.serializeAsOmittedField(pojo, jgen, provider);
      }
   }
   ...
};
FilterProvider filters = new SimpleFilterProvider().addFilter("MyFilter", columnFilter);

String result = mapper.writer(filters).writeValueAsString(MyDTOObj);
```

I see that I can't catch the moment of `nestedDTO.name` field serialization by this `serializeAsField()` realization. Explain to me how I can get it, please.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to skip serialization/deserialization of a field, just annotate it with `@JsonIgnore` :

```
public MyDTO {
   public int id;
   public List<MyNestedDTO> nestedDTO;

   public MyNestedDTO {
       public int id;
       @JsonIgnore
       public String name;

       ... 
   }

   ...
}
```